# Going between hex bytes and strings

Tags: python, hex

I am sure the solution is easy, but I haven't found it online. I might be just not searching as I should.

I want to be able to easily change between a character and its bits and hex representation in python. I usually do it as follows:

If I have a character, say chr(97), the letter "a", I can get its bit representation by

`byte_character=chr(97).encode()`

Or it's hex rep by

`hex_character=chr(97).encode().hex()`

and to going back I can use

`bytes.fromhex(hex_character).decode()`

`byte_character.decode()`

This works fine for most characters but for some of them the encoding uses more than one character. An example is `chr(140)` that when encoded gives 2 bytes:

`chr(140).encode()`

gives

`b'\xc2\x8c'`

rather than just `b'\x8c'` as I expect. Can you explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think there is anything wrong? Because you get more than one byte? `chr` returns the string representing a character specified by a Unicode point. There are 149,878 characters with code points in Unicode version 15.1. They cannot all be represented by one byte, since there are only 256 values one byte can have.

Comment: Or is it because you thought 140, being less than 256, would fit in 1 byte? If they used up every possible byte value for single-byte encodings of code points less than 256, there wouldn't be any way to encode higher code points. Any higher code point would look like a sequence of lower-valued code points.

Comment: Well I was expecting. b'\x8c' because 8*16+12=140. so 8c in base 16 is 140 in base 10. Isn't that how chr and encode are supposed to work?. It is for cryptography so I take two strings, change each character to a number using `ord` and then xor with a key so I never leave the 256 range. (It is for Coursera's mooc on cryptography in case your are familiar)

Comment: @DavidJaramillo so what if `b'x8c'` has a byte value of 140. What is the relevance of that? I think you fundamentally misunderstand `.encode`. Why would you expect a utf-8 encoding to give you one byte here? the point of encode is to create *bytes that correspond to that unicode string in a particular encoding*, defaulting to UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't have been using .encode(). The fact that `b'x8c'` has a byte value of 140 is what is important for me. what I want to do is to easily exchange `b'\x8c`, `chr(140)`, and `"8c"`. The answers gave me a way to do this so I'll mark the question solved. Thanks for all your comments!

Comment: There are two concepts involved. Unicode is a coded character set where each character codepoint, normally represented as a hexadecimal number of up to six hexadecimal digits. The second representation is the how each character is encoded as a sequence of bytes, either a single byte, double byte or multibyte encoding.  So the codepoint of þ is 00FE. Encoded as UTF-8 it is the byte sequence b'\xc3\xbe', as UTF-16-le it is b'\xfe\x00', as ISO-8859-1 it is b'\xfe'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is the 0 .. 255 byte range, you can use the `latin1` ([ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) encoding:

```
>>> chr(140).encode('latin1')
b'\x8c'
>>> chr(255).encode('latin1')
b'\xff'
>>> chr(256).encode('latin1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0100' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Your original attempt was using the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding by default, which emits multiple bytes for code points above 127:

```
>>> chr(140).encode()
b'\xc2\x8c'
>>> chr(127).encode()
b'\7f'
>>> chr(128).encode()
b'\xc2\x80'
>>> chr(12345).encode()
b'\xe3\x80\xb9'
```

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8(the default method of encoding unless specified) encodes any Unicode codepoint >128 (0x7F) in two or more bytes, so when the result of chr(x) is >128, it returns two or more bytes.

To fix this there are two solutions.

Use 'latin1' encoding to have it return 1 byte on a 0-255 scale.

```
x = chr(140)
byte = x.encode('latin1')
print(x)
>>> b'\x8c'
```

Another solution is Python has a built-in function, to_bytes. Using this method does not require converting the number beforehand. You can also specify the number of bytes you want to be returned in the first argument.

```
x = 140
byte = x.to_bytes(1, 'little')
print(byte)
>>> b'\x8c'
```

Both of these should work fine for what you are trying to accomplish.